# Is it possible to wrap DIV´s around form-elements in web2py controller

Tags: python, web2py

When you define a form in the controller like:

```
form = crud.update(db.my_table, my_id)
```

is it possible to simply wrap an extra DIV around certain form-elements, in this case Inputs:

```
for input in form.elements('input'):
    wrap_div_around(input)
```

and update the form with the wrapped input?

Comment: Note, `Crud` has been deprecated. Use `SQLFORM.process()` and `SQLFORM.grid()` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `replace` argument to `.elements()`, which can be a function that takes the original element and returns a new element:

```
form.elements('input', replace=wrap_div_around)
```

You might also consider creating a custom `formstyle` function that generates the exact form markup you are looking for. For examples of `formstyle` functions, see https://github.com/web2py/web2py/blob/ad43249f6148402890077a0a649e46b42fa6a8ab/gluon/sqlhtml.py#L886-L1083.